# False XAML Error Message

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, error-handling

This is my code :

```
<Window x:Class="NoteBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NoteBox"
    Title="NoteBox" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DotConverter x:Key="DotConverter"/>
    <local:NotesConverter x:Key="NotesConverter"/>
    <local:NoteAccidentalConverter x:Key="NoteAccidentalConverter"/>
    <local:BackgroundConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="OemPeriod" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="Blank"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D0" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="Rest"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D1" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N1"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D2" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N2"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D3" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N3"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D4" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N4"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D5" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N5"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D6" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N6"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D7" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N7"/>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="P" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="SHARP"/>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="T" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="FLAT"/>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="OemPlus" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="OCTAVE+"/>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="OemMinus" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="OCTAVE-"/>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="OemPeriod" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="DOT+"/>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="OemComma" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="DOT-"/>
</Window.InputBindings>

<Grid x:Name="grid" Margin="10,5,10,5"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Background="{Binding IsSelectedOrFocused, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
               Text="b"
               Visibility="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Accidental, Converter={StaticResource NoteAccidentalConverter}, ConverterParameter=FL, Mode=OneWay}" 
               FontSize="15" FontFamily="CourierNew" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Path Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Fill"
          Visibility="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Accidental, Converter={StaticResource NoteAccidentalConverter}, ConverterParameter=SP, Mode=OneWay}" >
        <Path.Data>
            <LineGeometry StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <LineGeometry.Transform>
                    <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="30"/>
                </LineGeometry.Transform>
            </LineGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
               Text="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Note, Converter={StaticResource NotesConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 
               FontSize="15" FontFamily="CourierNew" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="2.5,0,2.5,0"/>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Octave, Converter={StaticResource DotConverter}, ConverterParameter=TOP, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         Margin="{Binding Margin}" Fill="{Binding Fill}" 
                         Width="{Binding Diameter}" Height="{Binding Diameter}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Octave, Converter={StaticResource DotConverter}, ConverterParameter=BOT, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                         Margin="{Binding Margin}" Fill="{Binding Fill}" 
                         Width="{Binding Diameter}" Height="{Binding Diameter}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Dot, Converter={StaticResource DotConverter}, ConverterParameter=RIGHT, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Margin="{Binding Margin}" Fill="{Binding Fill}" 
                         Width="{Binding Diameter}" Height="{Binding Diameter}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

**And this is the problematic one**

```
<Path Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Fill"
          Visibility="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Accidental, Converter={StaticResource NoteAccidentalConverter}, ConverterParameter=SP, Mode=OneWay}" >
    <Path.Data>
        <LineGeometry StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <LineGeometry.Transform>
                <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="30"/>
            </LineGeometry.Transform>
        </LineGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

On the XAML, the `</Path.Data>` part is **ALWAYS** blue-underlined, but, if I compile it **and there's no other error**, it run successfully, without even displaying an error / warning message.

**BUT**

If there any "other" error, then, this keep showing on the error message table : `Closing tag for element '<LineGeometry>' was not found.`

**AND**

If "the other" error fixed, then `Closing tag for element '<LineGeometry>' was not found.` is gone too.

**SO**

It's just a "visual" problem. (Not sure how to say it)

Any idea what caused this, and how to fix it so it won't be underlined ever again? **(It's really unpleasant in the eye)**

Updated

Comment: I have tried your XAML snippet (without `{Binding}`, of course) in both VS2010 and VS2013 and there are no blue underlines or error list window items. Could you maybe post a small but complete XAML document that demonstrates the problem you observed? Furthermore, are you using third-party editor plugins like ReSharper? If yes, maybe try to disable them and restart VS; this might fix wrong error messages in the editor.

Comment: @fmunkert Updated. And, I don't use any XAML editor plugins (only XArrange on the code side).